# What would go wrong if i move /var from one machine to another?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, aws

I have a AWS EC2 instance (lets call it Eye1) with a 500GB EBS as secondary storage mounted at `/var`.

Now I want to migrate my environment to a different EC2 instance (lets call in Eye2). The new instance was initialised by other team members by installing python2.7, tensorflow, opencv and other libraries required for ML and CV alpong with apache2, mysql, php.

Now I am require to detach the EBS (which has `/var` contents of Eye1) to reattached it the the new EC2 and mount it at `/var` or Eye2.

What would happen to the original `/var` contents of Eye2 and what could go wrong if I replace the same with `/var` contents of Eye1?

Note: I am aware that Files, websites and applications hosted on Eye1's `/var/www/html` would replace that of Eye2. This is what my intent as the web root of Eye2 is empty.

My question is if this move would hurt any OS level configurations and mess with the LAMP and Python + its dependencies.

I am OK with system logs being replaced as Eye2 is practically brand new and has no activities running on it. It was spawned afresh and then LAMP + Python + its dependencies were installed.

Comment: All this depends on how you have your system configured. You could do with profiling the processes that use /var

Comment: @RamanSailopal Eye2 has just Apache2, MySQL, PHP, Python + ML libraries installed just a few hours ago. Other than that it is clean as a whistle Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: So there are no other daemons running that write to /var?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Something I or my team has started or created? No. I want to know if OS or any configurations of python is located anywhere in /var which the migration will mess up. I dont care about system or apache logs. because there aren't any

Comment: Use lsof | grep "var" to make sure

Comment: @RamanSailopal Empty result! So I guess it is safe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68885/discussion-between-enemetch-and-raman-sailopal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all of it, as that's liable to break things.  There are quite a few directories you absolutely *SHOULD NOT* copy or share between systems, including (this is not an exhaustive list):

- Almost anything under `/var/lib`:  Among other things, this includes the database of installed packages for the system on most distros (copying this to another system **WILL** break that system, seriously, don't do this), and server state for stateful services (liable to break those services on both systems if it gets copied, and liable to cause issues in the future in your case).
- `/var/db`: Pretty much the same issues as `/var/lib`, just less widely used.
- `/var/log` and `/var/account`:  These contain logging and accounting data specific to the system they originated on.  Copying them will overwrite the data on the target system.  While this may not seem significant, it can be a serious pain in the arse when trying to fix a problem, because you don't necessarily know what's from the old system and what's form the new one, and you can't see anything from before the copy.
- `/var/spool`:  This is temporary storage for a wide variety of service specific data stored on the local system.  Includes the local mail queues, the local `at` batch queues, the local print queues, and other similar things.  All kinds of confusing things can happen if this gets copied (and it should also usually be excluded from backups too for the same reasons).

Additionally, the following directories can be excluded because there's no point in copying them (also not an exhaustive list):

- `/var/cache`:  This is used as temporary storage for cached data.  By definition, you can nuke pretty much anything in here without breaking things (though some things may take longer than they used to the first time you run them).
- `/var/tmp`: Similarly, temporary storage.
- `/var/run`: Not really an issue any more because it's a symlink to `/run` on most distros these days, but it used to be it's own directory, used for PID files and sockets.

In your particular case, you should just copy over the directories you actually want, not everything.  `/var/www` is almost always safe to copy over provided that your website is properly configured and you update your links to poiint to the new host name.  In particular, I would suggest just copying the data on-line, and then deleting the old EBS instance (provided you don't need to keep it around as a back up).

Comment: You were a tad late but you're right! Anyway I am on AWS and I was trying out things so nothing important went down. I did see that I was not able to log into mysql after the move. Got permission denied errors. Not sure if its related but I am going to respawm my servers and move only the /var/www directory